# What is the size of the buffer in serial communication with arduino uno?

Tags: serial

as it is in the question, i need to know what is the size of the biggest string that i can send using the serial port to the arduino.
Thank you

Comment: You may check the sources shipped with the Arduino IDE.

Comment: The size of the buffer and the size of the biggest string you can send are not necessarily related (if they are, that's really lazy programming on someone's part)

Answer (score 1):

That would be 64 bytes, providing the buffer is fully empty. See https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.h#L42-L43